# How do I ask google not to index certain parts of my page?

Tags: seo, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)

I was searching for an old review on my site today and I noticed that Google is indexing the headline text in my latest article list on every page that it appears, obviously I guess.

The problem is if I search for my Dragon's Lair review specifically to my site like this

http://www.google.co.za/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Alazygamer.net+dragons+lair+review

Then it returns a ton of pages that aren't appropriate as they aren't related to the review at all.

The reason why I care is that I have a second Dragon's Lair review that was posted years ago and now I can't find it.

Is there a way to hint to google that certain text isn't relevant to the actual content on the page?

is it a terrible idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to hint to google that certain text isn't relevant to the actual content on the page?

No.
That's about it. The engines–I'm not aware of *any* of them letting you do what you're asking about–decide for themselves what's relevant to them in documents.

> Then it returns a ton of pages that aren't appropriate as they aren't related to the review at all.

Actually, they *are* appropriate, at least insofar as that the text does appear on those pages. To be fair, the indexing appears to be coming specifically from the block of featured posts at top, where you've put the headlines in H2 tags, which makes that text pretty "important." Downgrading that might help with what you're after a bit, but there's no direct way to tell the engines to outright ignore a chunk of text.

What you're more concerned about is *relevance* and in that regard, the "correct" document does still show up at the top of results.

Comment: Yeah I understand what you are saying but in 3 hours time those headlines at the top will be different and no longer relevant which is my worry..