# Keep search engine from indexing specific content on your site

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)

I've got a pretty weird scenario that I was wondering someone could help me out with.

I recently created a blog site and noticed that search engines have been including the content of my footer in with the description.  This presents a problem because my footer is basic a brief legal statement saying that the views are my own and don't represent the company I work for (and yada yada yada).  So, basically, I need a way to prevent search engines from indexint that content in my footer or even my footer altogether.  I've been looking back through some of my SEO books and searching through forums but this doesn't seem possible.

1. Is it possible to keep search engines from indexing only certain content on a page?
2. If it isn't possible, what alternatives are there to ensure this legal mumbo jumbo doesn't show up in the results?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly #1 is not the solution to your problem, it is inadvisable to block some content on a page.

To solve this problem it would be easier to see the search query which you are searching in google and also the structure of your website. Here are some solutions you can try.

- Look into optimising your meta description tags on your website for your targetted keyword.
- Include more relevant text in the main body of your webpage.

Again it is hard to give specific solutions without looking at your website and search query.

Comment: +1 - the correct way to do this is to give the spiders something to actually read, which is done via the meta tags.