# SEO: How to stop specific sections of a page from being crawled?

Tags: seo, google, web-crawlers, duplicate-content

I would like to display customer reviews from another website (with their agreement) own my own site for certain product pages.

Using these 3rd party reviews would be helpful for users, though there's an issue with duplicate content as I'll be republishing these reviews from the other website.

I don't want to noindex the whole page as many of these product pages already rank well.

One option I'm considering is to place the review content in an iframe and then block the iframe's URL in the robots.txt, though I'm unclear as to whether this would be frowned upon by search engines.

Is there a best practice, recognized and accepted by Google, for noindexing or blocking crawling of certain sections of a page?

Comment: Duplicate: [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options - iframe, as you suggested by yourself, or adding them dynamically with JavaScript. There is no other way to prevent that content from indexing without using noindex on the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in an iframe can't be indexed in the first place. So if you're not wanting the page to be found by what is said in the reveiws, an iframe is definitely the way to go as it will also make it so that you won't have to worry about duplicate content.