# Get local search to focus on our main office address and ignore satellite offices without using text images

Tags: seo, local-seo

We have 1 head office and 2 satellite offices in different cities. Our SEO focuses on our head office in various citation listings. We have been recommended to change our contact page so that our satellite office addresses are displayed as images so that search engines only focus on the head office.

I think this makes sense for SEO, however having text as images is not considered good practice for Webdev/UX. Is there an alternate way to have search enginesignore the satellite addresses?

Comment: See also: [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you want the search engines to "only focus on the head office". Since search engines present information to users, this tells me that you want your users to also only focus on the head office. Is that correct?

If your satellite offices are irrelevant to your audience, then you should consider just not showing the addresses at all.

If your satellite offices are indeed relevant to your audience, however, then you should show them in plain, searchable text so that people can find them on the internet.