# Prevent search engines from indexing specific images on a page

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, images

A website I'm working on has a team section. Every team member has a dedicated site. On the site's bottom of each team member three other team members are displayed randomly.

[image: Site]

What happens here is that search engines index all four images. When I enter the name a specific team member into a search engine I get all four images as results. I want to show only the main image on top. **So, how can I prevent search engines from indexing the three images at the bottom?**

Answer (score 3):

You can write that section of the page using JavaScript that is blocked by robots.txt.   This is the general technique described in [Preventing robots from crawling specific part of a page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page).

#### HTML

```
<img src=/images/main-person.jpg> Text about the main person.
<script src=/js/3-random-people.js></script>
```

#### Robots.txt

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /js/3-random-people.js
```

### 3-random-people.js

```
document.write('<img src=/images/other-person-1.jpg>')
document.write('<img src=/images/other-person-2.jpg>')
document.write('<img src=/images/other-person-3.jpg>')
```

Comment: Thank you for linking the other post and explaining it here. I thought there might be other techniques as the other post is relatively old.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent those (three) images being indexed by returning an `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` header as part of the HTTP response.

This is easier if there is something in the image filename that differentiates the images you don't want indexed, or perhaps they are in a different subdirectory. You can then simply prevent indexing for any images in that subdirectory.

For example, store these images in a `/images/noindex` subdirectory. And if you are using Apache then you can do something like the following in `.htaccess` or your server config:

```
# Prevent indexing of certain images
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/images/noindex/" NOINDEX=1
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex" env=NOINDEX
```

Alternatively, you can prevent *crawling* of this subdirectory in `robots.txt` (which should also prevent indexing).

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /images/noindex/
```

---

**UPDATE:** You don't necessarily need to duplicate these images if the images are already stored in `/images` and these images do need to be indexed when they appear on other pages.

You could just modify the URL of these secondary images to include `/noindex` (as above), and internally rewrite the request to remove the `/noindex` path segment in order to serve the actual image.

Although, naturally, you still lose the benefit of client-side caching, since it still looks like two images from a user-agent perspective.

For example...

- Image is stored in `/images/person_xyz.jpg`
- URL references `/images/noindex/person_xyz.jpg`

Using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`, rewrite the request to remove `/noindex` and set an environment variable. Set the `X-Robots-Tag` response header based on this env var, similar to before:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove "/noindex" from image URL and set env var
RewriteRule ^(images/)noindex/([^.]+\.jpg)$ $1$2 [E=NOINDEX:1,L]

# Set "X-Robots-Tag: noindex" header if "/noindex" was present in URL
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex" env=REDIRECT_NOINDEX
```

Note that due to the *rewrite* (internal redirect), we need to check for `REDIRECT_NOINDEX`, rather than `NOINDEX` in the `Header` directive.

Alternatively, you could just append a query string to the image URL and avoid the rewrite. mod_rewrite is still required in order to examine the query string portion of the URL. For example, link to `/images/person_xyz.jpg?noindex`. Then, in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Set env var if query string set to "noindex"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^noindex$
RewriteRule ^images/ - [E=NOINDEX:1]

# Set "X-Robots-Tag: noindex" header if "noindex" was present in query string
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex" env=NOINDEX
```

Comment: Since there is only one image of each person I will have to serve the same image over two URLs: `/images/person_xyz.jpg` and `/images/noindex/person_xyz.jpg`. The image which is related to the team member site will be servers from the first URL and the random images of all team members will be served from the second URL.

Comment: Yes, you serve the same image over two URLs. However, you don't necessarily need to physically duplicate the image on the backend filesystem, you could just change the URL and internally rewrite the request. I've updated my answer. _Aside_ The secondary images look smaller in your example, so if you did "duplicate" the image, this could perhaps be a smaller/optimised version?

Comment: They are basically the same image just scaled down, so serving through a second URL should work without physically duplicating