# Is it possible to ignore href links on page in search results?

Tags: google-search

I've got a page that has been indexed by Google however the page requires users to select an option in a popup before continuing ie. Are you a practitioner? Yes/No

If the user selects yes the popup closes and they can view the content. If they select no they are taken to the consumer version of the page. I know there are ways around this (disable JS etc) but it works for the majority of users.

On the page there is some content and some links to PDF documents. The content and the documents are appearing in Google search results. The issue with this is that the PDF documents can be accessed directly from the search results without seeing the popup question. I've put the nofollow tag on the PDF but this will only stop google from indexing the content of the document. I also know the noindex is for the page level.

I'm also aware of the below but apparently not for search results.

```
<!--googleoff: index-->
```

Is there a way to notify search engines to index the content but ignore all links/PDF/whatever on particular pages while indexing the rest?

There are a number of similar questions answered however these are different issues from what I need. They relate to block indexing of PDF content or the entire page the pdf links live on. This is not what I want.

Comment: If you're trying to prevent Google from displaying a link from a page that appears in the site description/snippet or cache returned for your site in search results, then see [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/preventing-robots-from-crawling-specific-part-of-a-page) question.